# rails 3.0.9 auto_link linking text infront of http://

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So when I use the auto_link function on this text

also saw this on yammer...http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/27/former-facebook-vp-chamath-palihapitiya-leads-17m-round-in-enterprise-social-networking-platform-yammer

"yammer...http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/27/former-facebook-vp-chamath-palihapitiya-leads-17m-round-in-enterprise-social-networking-platform-yammer" gets auto_linked the "yammer..." gets inside the href link. Any one else having issues with this and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this particular behavior is exhibited, but I would guess that it has to do with `auto_link` trying to be protocol agnostic. Aaron Patterson has indicated that this method is inherently difficult to secure and requires a faster release cycle than Rails has, so they have removed it from Rails 3.1 and put it in a separate gem that adds the method back into ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper. You can probably use this gem for Rails 3.0.9 and it might behave differently in this situation.

https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

**Edit:**

A quick and dirty hack to fix this for you would be to do the following in a helper:

```
def your_auto_link(content)
  auto_link content.gsub(/([^ ])http:/, '\1 http:')
end
```

Comment: Thanks Corey, I did look at this gem but am not sure if I can use it in production because it says : REQUIREMENTS: rails >= 3.1. I tested  AUTO_LINK_RE regexs inside rublar and neither one is handling the above scenario.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look like the tests have coverage for parsing links out of real-life scenarios. Hopefully that'll change soon, and if you add failing tests for these scenarios and push back to the projet it might help speed things along (obviously more so if you contribute a patch that solves the problem).

Comment: Thanks @coryward for the above code snippet, The issue with that is that the gsub would replace the character preceding http:/ with a space, That may work for the above examples but if someone forgot a space between putting a link in and their text it would remove that character. But I do get the idea though. Also I will add failing tests to the rails_autolink project maybe later tonight.

Comment: Oh yeah, whoops. I'll fix now.